# Razor server side code block and Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

My application is MVC5 c#, trying to execute the following:

```
@{
    var s = Model.PhysicalExam;
    if (s == null)
        {
            <script>
                alert("1");
                $("#newSale1").hide();
            </script>
        }
    else
        {
            <script>
                alert("2");
                $("#newSale1").show();
            </script>
        }
}
```

Alert works, however does not hide or show the button.  Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery by the time that script runs?

Comment: And does the element with `id="newSale1"` exist at this time. This is a terrible way of rendering scripts in you page.

Comment: Yes to both comments.

Comment: @hncl, are you sure that the layout constructor is called after documentready? because I am pretty sure its called first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `newSale1` maybe isn't loaded in the DOM when that script code is executed. You should probably put those blocks inside a document ready event.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: You are correct, I was calling it before.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I might go with something like this at the bottom of the page

```
<script type='text/javascript">
   var isExamNull = @((Model.PhysicalExam == null).ToString());
   $(document).ready( function(){
      if (isExamNull)
         $("#newSale1").hide();
      else
         $("#newSale1").show();
    };)
</script>
```

Putting scripts at the bottom of the page lets the html render first, $(document).ready ensure that, well, the document is ready.  Using the @() will write your server side values into your scripts, another technique is to use a hidden and have the script check the value of the hidden.

Comment: Thank you, this will help in restructuring my page.